# Recursive JavaScript function using array doesn't work

Tags: jquery, arrays, recursion

I try to make a recursive function to delete files using jQuery and ajax to show the status of the process. The problem is, the first time the function is executed (index 0) everything is fine and the "output" is "1594.jpg". But when the index is incremented to 1, it's the second caracter of the chain filesToDelete, '5', then '9', and so on.

```
filesToDelete = new Array();
filesToDelete = '1594.jpg,my.png,test.ogg,Song.mp3,Apple_4S.mov,An App.exe';
filesToDelete = filesToDelete.split(',');

function ajaxDelete(itemList, cpt) {
    var tempItemList = itemList;

    //If cpt is not initialized, initialize it, make sure it's an integer
    if(isNaN(cpt)) cpt = 0*1;

    //If cpt is equal to the array, exit
    if(cpt >= itemList.length) return;

    //Current index
    var curIndex = cpt;
    //The value of the current index
    var current = itemList[curIndex];
    //DEBUG
    console.log('cpt:'+cpt+' index:'+curIndex+'  Value:'+itemList[curIndex]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "deleteFile.php?id="+current,
        beforeSend: function(){
            progressText('Suppression de '+current);
        },
        success: function(data){
            progressText('Suppression...');
            //Index + 1
            cpt++;
            //RECURTION
            setTimeout("ajaxDelete('"+itemList+"', "+cpt+")",1);
        }
    });
}
```

Any help is welcomed, with explanation if possible..

Thanks !

Comment: How are you calling the `ajaxDelete()` with `filesToDelete`?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better done on the server directly?

Comment: @deceze: No because I want a feedback for the user and event if I use flush(*) in php, AJAX still wait for the complete page to be load before returning the result.

Comment: @Jared: I'm not calling it actually :), but I think I should because it will take less memory if the array got like 200 indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on the ajax success method for this, if it fails for whatever reason your stuck.

You should do an ajax call per file to delete or better yet send the Array of files to the server and let it take care of it.

```
for (i = 0; i <= filesToDelete.length; i++)
{
    // Ajax Call
    $.ajax({

    });
}
```

Comment: Oh damn, never thought of that, thank you so much, trying it right away!

Comment: Working like a charm! Thx man! EDIT: Is it possible to wait for an answer from the ajax request before skipping to the other index?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in `itemList` as a string, but believe it to be an array. (In the `setTimeout` call, I mean.)

But I agree with the comment/answer; ew!

Comment: How can I paste it as an array? (just for learning, I'll take Miste Jeremy solution :))

Answer (score 1):

Your setTimeout call is executing a string command:

```
setTimeout("ajaxDelete('"+itemList+"', "+cpt+")",1);
```

When you concatenate strings and objects, it takes the value of toString() on that object.  In the case of an array, that will give you this:

```
ajaxDelete('1594.jpg,my.png,test.ogg,Song.mp3,Apple_4S.mov,An App.exe', 1)
```

And strings will accept brackets and give you that character.  This will give you '5'

```
'1594.jpg,my.png,test.ogg,Song.mp3,Apple_4S.mov,An App.exe'[1]
```

You could omit that parameter and use filesToDelete directly in your call...

Comment: Thanks Jason fot the explanation, now that you have explained it to me, I feel stupid XD... Next time I'll be more careful, thank you

Comment: No sorry Jason still getting an error from FireBug: setTimeout("ajaxDelete("+filesToDelete+", "+cpt+")",1);

Comment: I meant don't even take itemList as a parameter, declare your function "ajaxDelete(cpt)" and you can use the existing filesToDelete array.  Since you just set the value outside your function it should be on your window object.

Comment: Okay tahnk you! But let say I can't, how should I parse the array in the function unsing ajaxDelete(...) ?

Comment: Maybe you could consider that parameter to be the comma-separated value string, and split it into a NEW array varaible inside your function?  Then you're passing it as a string every time..

Comment: You can pass a function to setTimeout instead of a string.  In this case the function can have access to your parameter.  The problem is you are creating a stack of functions that keep the parameters in scope I believe...  Maybe not...   http://jsfiddle.net/WqTed/